# enabling https with gerrit results in 502 bad gateway

Tags: https, reverse-proxy, gerrit

I have added a load balancer that routes https traffic to a gerrit instance I have (to port 8080).

Using `tcpdump` I do see that if I access `https://foo.gerrit.bar` there is traffic with port 8080 coming into my gerrit instance.

I assume something about gerrit config that I'm missing.

I have added just the httpd reverse proxy setting:

```
[httpd]
        listenUrl = proxy-http://127.0.0.1:8080/r/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that this is a stupid typo and I want to keep it here in case some one else copy pastes this somewhere (aka copy-pasta).

```
[httpd]
        listenUrl = proxy-https://127.0.0.1:8080/r/
```

`proxy-https` and not `proxy-http`